# difference: maven assembly:assembly versus assembly:single goals?

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, alexa-skills-kit, jar-with-dependencies

I'm trying to build an alexa-app, with some annotations driven dependency injection (dagger 2) code. The [alexa-sample-skills-test](https://github.com/amzn/alexa-skills-kit-java) gives example pom and instructs to use the following command to build a jar with dependencies.

```
mvn assembly:assembly -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies package
```

Building using the above fails with the exception and output listed in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408706/java-lang-illegalstateexception-endpostable-already-set/36421345#36421345). After a little digging into [maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), I found out that the assembly:assembly goal uses non-standard build processes that can wreak havocs. The maven assembly-plugin docs instead, recommends to use the assembly:single goal. Hence, I use the following command instead:

```
mvn assembly:single -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies package
```

Voila.. the code compilation and linking goes fine. I get a [project-name]-jar-with-dependencies.jar file. However, when I upload the jar in the amazon server and try to test the skill, the test fails. The log says that the class: echo.client.AccountInfoStreamHandler could not be found (ClassNotFoundException). This class just happens to a root launcher class, I suppose.

Now, I nuke all the dagger 2 dependencies and repeat the same with the simplest code-base. The first maven command (assembly:assembly) works. The second maven command (assembly:single) fails with the same 'ClassNotFoundException' error. What am I doing wrong? I am not too familiar with maven, and this is really the FIRST time I'm trying to troubleshoot a maven command. Any suggestions, pointers, recommendations is greatly appreciated.

For Reference, the POM file is below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.apil.echo.accountant</groupId>
  <artifactId>echo-device-client</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>Echo Device Client</name>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>alexa-skills-kit-repo</id>
      <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>Maven Central</id>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.plaid</groupId>
      <artifactId>plaid-java</artifactId>
      <version>0.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>alexa-skills-kit</groupId>
      <artifactId>alexa-skills-kit</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.6.v20130930</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.6.v20130930</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.10</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.40</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- using mockito for test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
          <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
          <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
          <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <property name="disableRequestSignatureCheck" value="false"/>
    <property name="supportedApplicationIds" value=""/>
    <property name="timestampTolerance" value="150"/>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>Launcher</mainClass>
            <systemProperties>
              <systemProperty>
                <key>javax.net.ssl.keyStore</key>
                <value>/insert/your/path/java-keystore.jks</value>
              </systemProperty>
              <systemProperty>
                <key>javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword</key>
                <value>insert_your_password</value>
              </systemProperty>
              <systemProperty>
                <key>com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.disableRequestSignatureCheck</key>
                <value>${disableRequestSignatureCheck}</value>
              </systemProperty>
              <systemProperty>
                <key>com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.supportedApplicationIds</key>
                <value>${supportedApplicationIds}</value>
              </systemProperty>
              <systemProperty>
                <key>com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.timestampTolerance</key>
                <value>${timestampTolerance}</value>
              </systemProperty>
            </systemProperties>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Well, per the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), I'd say the biggest difference is that essentially all goals _except_ `single` have been deprecated.

Comment: yapp. But in terms of what they're doing, why does one work and not the other? For most except exceptional cases, both these goals ought to be doing the same thing, no?

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using the gradle build scripts that were more recently provided for the alexa-sample-skills-test. Preliminary build inspections shows that the required classes: echo.client.[Class..] does exist in the resulting build.

Inspecting the uber-jars that resulted from the above maven commands, I noticed that

`mvn assembly:assembly ...`

resulted in a jar that had the echo.client package with the missing class. However,

`mvn assembly:single...`

resulted in a jar that did NOT have the echo.client package, or any of the application classes defined within the package. Hence, I was getting the ClassNotFoundException. I still haven't figured out why this was happening. However, I think the time is ripe to switch to 'gradle' from this point on...